# Cross scripting error on the Retrieved Database data

Tags: java, xss, veracode

I see a Cross Scripting injection error on the statement that follows the execute update. How do I sanitize the output to rid it of Cross scripting errors..
I have a simple code snippet which uses PreparedStatement to run a select and returns the values which is retrieved on the front end GUI screen.

XSS Flaw message:**"The tainted data originated from an earlier call to java.sql.ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName. "**

Java code:

```
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try {
            List alist= new ArrayList();
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            int count = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                 alist.add(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i))   //Flaw seems to point to this.
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
        //close connections
        }
        return alist;
```

***Full Veracode Flaw:***
**Attack Vector:** javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter.print

**Number of Modules** Affected: 1

**Description:** This call to javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter.print() contains a cross-site scripting (XSS) flaw. The application populates the HTTP response with untrusted input, allowing an attacker to embed malicious content, such as Javascript code, which will be executed in the context of the victim's browser. XSS vulnerabilities are commonly exploited to steal or manipulate cookies, modify presentation of content, and compromise confidential information, with new attack vectors being discovered on a regular basis. The first argument to print() contains tainted data from the variable getHtml(). The tainted data originated from an earlier call to java.sql.ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName. The tainted data is directed into an output stream returned by javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter.

Comment: Can you add a stacktrace or some other information about the error? There can't be any error concerning XSS on the medadata of a result set. And there can't be a problem with XSS because you are using prepared statements which are used to prevent XSS. So the error has to be something else I think...

Comment: unfortunately this is not an error but a cross scripting flaw and so there is no stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was finally able to figure out the problem.

My Query was:

```
SELECT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_A||'-'||COLUMN_B FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE COLUMN_C IS NULL;
```

There are a few things I did...

1) Add an alias name to my column and used `rs.getMetaData().getcolumnlabel(i)` instead of `rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i)`. This makes sure to eliminate pipeline or hyphens from the output resultset name.

2) Used OWASP's `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(unsafeString)` instead of using `Encode.forHtml(escapeHtml)` and `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(escapeHtml)` on the variable passed to the prepared statement.

Ouput behavior of || and - when passing them through the various escape functions.
Input: `String unsafeString ="<'HELLO'-||>";`

**Outputs:**

`Encode.forHtml(unsafeString)` is `&lt;&#39;HELLO&#39;-||&gt;`
`StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(unsafeString)` is `&lt;'HELLO'-||&gt;`
`ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(unsafeString)` is `&lt;&#x27;HELLO&#x27;-&#x7c;&#x7c;&gt;`
`ESAPI.encoder().decodeForHTML(safeString from above line)` `is <'HELLO'-||>`

If the Output is sent to the jsp to be rendered back on the html then you dont have to do the decodeStep..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why a `ResultSetMetaData` object is calling a servlet method, but if I do understand it correctly it is used to print something in the servlet. But because all the data in your `ResultSetMetaData` is comming from your database's meta data (which can't possibly include javascript code or other XSS riscs) it should be save in this case.

`ResultSetMetaData` is a common used class (and used sinze a long time) so I realy don't think that this is a problem in current java versions.

So I'm not shure how to fix this, but I'm pretty shure that this is not a problem, because it's not possible to add any maleware code (javascript or sql injection code) in the metadata of your database.